# Is using a powered USB hub Raspberry Pi DC power and USB data a good idea? Or does it create an odd, circular dependency that could blow the hub?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, usb-hub

I have Raspberry Pi model A which has only one USB port. So I bought the cheapest electrically powered USB hub (AC adapter that has an output of DC 5V at 1000 mA) I could find—kind of in the spirit of Raspberry Pi as being accessible because it’s cheap, really mostly because I’m cheap myself—for adding Wi-Fi and other things. Here’s what it looks like:

[image]

My “genius”—or depending on your answers not so genius—solution for providing a power source for the Raspberry Pi was to plug it’s power inlet into the USB hub and then, of course, plug the hub itself in the Raspberry Pi’s only USB port, creating a sort of a circular dependency. Well not really a dependency, but you get the idea.

It worked fine with the first USB hub I got for about an hour before the hub silently died and just stopped working. But I blamed it on the damage that the hub had. It arrived with scratch marks on it. I ordered another one of the same model and this one lasted around thirty seconds of actual work before making a loud noise and starting to smell like burnt plastic.

So, my question is this: Are my problems because of low quality product? Or am I causing some kind of short circuiting by doing this?

Comment: It is best to keep questions short and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common to use a hub for powering the Raspberry Pi as explained on [eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#Power):

> It is possible to power the Raspberry Pi from a powered USB hub the
>   Raspberry Pi controls, but only on ‘dumb’ devices, that allow the port
>   to supply the full current without waiting for the usb device to ask
>   for it[4]. As the power input of the Raspberry Pi doesn’t have its
>   data leads connected, there is no chance for a communication loop of
>   some sorts.

One thing to consider is that a lot of cheap hubs are badly designed, don’t comply with the USB specification and could theoretically damage the Raspberry Pi. In particular, many can feed back power to the Pi the “wrong way” through the Raspberry Pi’s USB host ports, an effect referred to as “back-powering.” It is not necessarily a problem, but it bypasses the safety fuses and if it were to output excessive voltage it could burn out components and even cause a fire.

The hub in your picture looks like [the model shown here](http://thepihut.com/products/7-port-usb-hub-for-the-raspberry-pi) which is supposed to be suitable for use with the Raspberry Pi as it doesn’t back-power. It’s not impossible your model could be a fake version though, so it might be worth mentioning where you bought it.

At any rate I’m not sure the hub is designed to actually power the Raspberry Pi, at best it probably only outputs 500mA maximum per port which is is less than the recommended 700mA. A common problem with cheaper products is that the voltage may drop below tolerances at higher loads. Sometimes they go bang when it all gets too much. The PSU that came with your hub is only rated at 1 amp (1000 mA) which seems rather low considering there are 7 ports.

I have used a hub to power a model B but that was with a high-quality [Pimoroni](http://shop.pimoroni.com) hub made for the Raspberry Pi. It was designed not to back-power and had a dedicated port with increased current output specifically for powering the Raspberry Pi. I would recommend one of these as it worked perfectly for this and the build quality was far superior to other hubs I have used in general.

Comment: I've run a keyboard a mouse and a HDD off a belkin powered hub alongside a raspi. I'm pretty certain the OP's specific hub is just faulty personally